# Swift - how to implement protocol methods in function

Tags: swift

In android, it is possible to implement interface methods during function call. For example, the declaration of interface and function:

```
//interface
interface exampleCallback {
    void success(String response);
    void error(String error);
}

//function
void exampleFunction(exampleCallback cb) {
    //do something
}
```

And the function call:

```
exampleFunction(new exampleCallback() {
    @Override
    public void success(String response) {
        //custom method implementation
    }
    @Override
    public void error(String error) {
        //custom method implementation
    }
});
```

That is, the success/error methods can be customized for each function call of the exampleFunction.
However, after some google search, I can only find example codes for implementing protocol methods in class or struct declaration, in which the methods can no longer be customized. I know I can pass escaping closure as function parameter to achieve the goal, i.e., customize callback function for each function call. But just wonder if I can use protocol to do the similar thing...

Comment: Swift does not have anonymous objects. To implement callbacks, read about Closures instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an enumeration with associated values:

```
enum Result {
    case success(String)
    case error(CustomError)
}
enum CustomError: Error {
    case expired(String)
}
```

And use the enumeration cases in a completion handler of your method to pass your custom string:

```
func exampleFunction(completion: @escaping (Result) -> ()) {
    if condition {
        completion(.success("Success String"))
    } else {
        completion(.error(.expired("Error String"))) 
    }
}
```

When calling your method you can switch your enumeration and do your custom implementation there as well as use the associated value returned in your callback:

```
exampleFunction { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(response):
        // custom method implementation
        // use your (response) string here
    case let .error(error):
        // custom method implementation
        // use your (error.localizedDescription) string here
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jo4cycaij3sz7dx/AACh0A7tfU837k4meuLbr-jMa?dl=1)

Comment: Why call it `Callback` when it should be `Result` in the sense that `Result<T>` and the failure case of `Error`. If the OP want it can turn `String` error into actual `Error` using `LocalizedError`

Comment: I used the naming trying to match what OP used in his question. Of course I could create an enumeration error with string as associated value to pass instead of a String in the error case but thats not what OP is asking here

Comment: @Lamar updated the playground sample to reflect your suggestion https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jo4cycaij3sz7dx/AACh0A7tfU837k4meuLbr-jMa?dl=1

Comment: I was just pointing out, since your associated enum look similar to `Result` I was like why not just name that and follow its requirement

Comment: @Lamar update the code in the answer also. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes in Java is really just a "workaround" for the absence of functions as "first class citizens".

In swift, functions are first class citizens, so you don't actually need to pass an anonymous class that implements a single method. You just pass that method (somewhat similar to Java 8's lambdas).

This in Java:

```
interface ActionListener {
    void actionPerformed();
}
```

Can just be represented by a closure type in Swift:

```
() -> Void
```

Instead of doing this:

```
someMethod(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed() { ... }
});
```

You do this in Swift:

```
someMethod { ... }
```

---

What if your interface in Java has multiple methods to implement?

In that case, you can't use one single closure to represent them all. You need to either

- create a protocol with multiple methods and implement it in a struct or class. You see this pattern a lot in `UIKit`. Views and view controllers often has a `XXXDelegate`.
- pass a tuple of closures